# Unable to delete a contact from Contact List in Android phone

Tags: contacts, whatsapp-messenger, nexus-5x

Phone: Nexus 5x
Operating System: Android 7.0

When I try to delete a contact in contact list of phone it displays the error message:

```
Contacts from your read-only accounts cannot be deleted, but they can be hidden.
Cancel Hide
```

When I see the details of the contact, I cannot see the number but I can see it in the Whatsapp contact details.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your phone's **System settings→Accounts→**(select your account), then turn off **Contacts sync**.

After that try to delete the contacts from the contacts app.